# What is the timeline for The Lord of the Rings trilogy?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, timeline

The Lord of the Rings trilogy obviously covers a lot of time. How many months/years pass from the beginning of *The Fellowship of the Ring* until the end of *The Return of the King*? A timeline of events would be exceptionally helpful.

Comment: doesn't answer the question, but a related info-graphic: http://xkcd.com/657/large/

Comment: *Appendix B: The Tale of Years (Chronology of the Westerlands)* covers from Second Age, through the Third Age (in greater detail for *The Great Years*), and into The Fourth Age. This reflects the books of course and not the changes in the films.

Comment: @Richard Yes, the right answer is "read the appendices".

Comment: Call it my crusade but technically it's not a trilogy; the fact it was put into three parts has to do with the actual length as well as lack of resources post war. He notes the problems with calling it a trilogy, doesn't consider it one himself (as such) and the 50th anniversary is actually one volume. Also each volume of the three are two different 'books'. Either way it's a single story. The Tolkien Estate notes this somewhere although I'm not certain off hand. Yes, yes, it's an old question but still. And yes this means OED is incorrect.

Comment: @Pryftan YES! When I saw this question, I hoped that someone pointed that out. I think Tolkien refers to it as one novel in six books.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The best timeline I have seen which includes dates and times for the *Fellowship of the Ring* can be found at [The Lord of the Rings Fanatics network](https://web.archive.org/web/20160729054219/http://www.lordotrings.com/books/timeline.asp). There are four parts to their timeline and each lists the paths of the major participants in the fellowship and events related to the characters. The fine graphic created at [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/657/large/), is more of a story-path tracker than an actual timeline.

[image: LotR Timeline, Part 1]
[image: LotR Timeline, Part 2]
[image: LotR Timeline, Part 3]
[image: LotR Timeline, Part 4]

*The Lord of the Rings* Timeline was designed by: Philip Kooijman © 2001.

Comment: You may as well add the remaining parts.

Comment: This is a great timeline, but it leaves out the vast majority of the time that elapses in the _Lord of the Rings_ (at least in the books). Seventeen years pass between the day Bilbo leaves Hobbiton and the day Frodo does the same. The movies aren't quite so clear about how much time has gone by there.

Comment: I'm not sure if one of my edits missed approval, but I could swear I had all four timeline images copied here.  EDIT:  Oh, it seems everything prior to 3018 *is* missing.

Comment: @Plutor The movies must have erased my memory, I had forgotten that a lot of time passed between Bilbo's departure and Frodo's. Other than research by Gandalf and Gollum being found by Aragorn and then captured by Mordor what happens in that 17 year span?

Comment: @ahsteele The movies altered those events so there wasn't a span of time.  Bilbo decides to leave, he leaves, and then Gandalf sets Frodo on the quest all over the course of like 2 days.

Comment: @ahsteele Those are the main events. Also, Aragorn hands Gollum to the elves in Mirkwood and then Mordor attacks and releases him. Here's the full list of everything the Encyclopedia of Arda has from 3001 TA to 3018 TA: http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/chronicle.html?startyear=3001&startage=3&endyear=3018&endage=3

Comment: Do we know what calendar this timeline uses?  I know the Shire calendar had 30 days in each month, but I don't know anything about the other calendars.  None of these dates are higher than the 30th, and there is a February 29th in there, so either that was a leap year or the calendar used is different from ours.

Comment: @WadCheber Shire calendar, with the month names translated as the Gregorian months that they most nearly overlap, as was generally done in LotR (which means that "September 22" is actually Halimath 22, which corresponds about to September 13th). Determined by the fact that it identifies Bilbo and Frodo's birthday as September 22, but other points of alignment should be possible.

Comment: This of course only covers the directly narrated events (and, as remarked, does not start with the preparations for Bilbo’s birthday party); the indirectly narrated events cover a far greater period, and for those as well one should check out the appendices.

Comment: @hobbs The use of Gondorian years 3018 and 3019 instead of Shire Reckoning 1418 and 1419 argues against that.

Comment: @Spencer I mean, that is weird, but there's still the fact that it annotates the party as "Sept 22", so I think it's a mixed calendar.

Comment: the XKCD graphic is based on the movies

Answer (score 37):

The short answer is roughly 20 years.  The passing of the ring from Bilbo to Frodo takes place far in advance of most of the story.  Most of the action happens over the course of 3 years.

The long answer is distilled from [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103172323/http://tuckborough.net/chronology.html#Great-Years) *extremely* thorough chronology, here's a rundown.  All events take place during the Third Age.  Let me know what events you'd like me to add.

- 3001 - Bilbo Baggins turns 111.  He announces his plan to leave The Shire and does so.  Left behind, on purpose, is The One Ring.  Frodo and Merry find the ring amongst Bilbo's possessions.  Sometime late this year Gandalf suspects that Bilbo's ring is The One Ring.
- 3004-3008 - Gandalf visits Frodo periodically, presumably to keep his eye on the new Ringbearer.
- 3017 - Gollum is captured by Sauron's forces.  He's tortured for information on The Ring.
- 3018

  - Aragorn captures Gollum and turns him over to King Thranduil of Mirkwood.  He's held there, and questioned by Gandalf, who then leaves for the Shire.
  - Gandalf visits Frodo, and determines the ring is The One Ring.  This begins the quest, Frodo and Sam make plans to depart.  A few months later, they depart with Pippin joining them.
  - Orcs attack Mirkwood, Gollum escapes.
  - Merry joins the group.
  - The hobbits arrive in Bree at the Prancing Pony.  They meet up with Aragorn.
  - Aragorn and the hobbits arrive in Rivendell.  At the end of the year, the Fellowship of the Ring is formed and departs Rivendell.
- 3019

  - They fail to cross the mountains via the pass of Caradhras, so they travel through Moria.  Gollum starts following the Fellowship.  In Moria, they are attacked by Orcs and a Balrog.  Gandalf is separated from the rest of the Fellowship while battling a Balrog.
  - The Fellowship goes to Lothlórien.  There they meet Galadriel, and receive gifts.  They depart down the great river Anduin.
  - The Breaking of the Fellowship:

    - Boromir attempts to steal the ring.
    - Sam and Frodo head to Mordor.
    - The group is attacked by Uruk-hai.
    - Boromir dies in battle defending Merry and Pippin.  They are abducted, and taken towards Isengard.
    - Aragorn, Legolas, and Gimli put Boromir into a funeral boat and follow the Uruk-hai who have Merry and Pippin.
  - The Uruk-hai are attacked by the Rohirrim.  Merry and Pippin escape and meet Treebeard and the Ents.
  - Aragorn, Legolas, and Gimli meet Gandalf, who is now 30% whiter.  They head to Edoras.  Then they head to Helm's Deep, and the Battle of Helm's Deep happens.  Gandalf splits off prior to Helm's Deep and heads to Isengard.
  - The Ents attack Isengard.
  - Gandalf arrives at Isengard, and meets Merry, Pippin, and the Ents.  Gandalf heads to Helm's Deep with backup of men and Huorns (ancient and powerful tree-like beings).  They arrive at Helm's Deep and contribute to the victory.  Gandalf, Aragorn, Legolas, Gimli, King Theoden and his company go to Isengard to meet Saruman.  Saruman is imprisoned.
  - Gollum joins Frodo and Sam.  They head to the Black Gate, then instead head to Minas Morgul.
  - Pippin uses the palantír, and is revealed to Sauron.  Sauron mistakes him for the Ringbearer.  Pippin and Gandalf head to Edoras, then onwards to Gondor.  Merry swears fealty to Theoden.
  - Theoden's men gather at Dunharrow.  Aragorn, Legolas, and Gimli take the Paths of the Dead.
  - Sam and Frodo are captured by Faramir's men.  They are brought to Faramir, but he releases them, and they head to the path near Minas Morgul.  They sneak in to Mordor, and make their way towards Mount Doom.
  - Aragorn, Legolas, and Gimli emerge from the Paths of the Dead, and start working their way towards Gondor, while defeating some of the backup for Sauron's forces.
  - In Minas Tirith, Pippin swears fealty to Denethor.
  - The Battle of the Pelennor Fields

    - Sauron's forces attack Minas Tirith.
    - Gandalf and the forces in Minas Tirith defend the siege.
    - Pippin and Gandalf save Faramir from Denethor's madness.
    - The Rohirrim, including Merry, attack Sauron's forces.
    - Aragorn, Legolas, Gimli, and the dead join the battle.
  - Aragorn heals a ton of people.  Then the plan is formed to keep Sauron distracted from Frodo and Sam's progress.  He, Gandalf, Legolas, Gimli, Pippin, and a host of others head to the Black Gate and meet the Mouth of Sauron and reject his terms.  They then battle Sauron's forces.
  - Frodo and Gollum destroy The One Ring in Mount Doom.  Frodo and Sam are rescued by Gandalf and the Great Eagles.
  - Everyone returns to Minas Tirith.
  - Aragorn is crowned King.  There was much rejoicing.
  - Frodo, Sam, Merry, and Pippin head home.  Saruman gets to the Shire first, and sets up shop in Bag End.  He enslaves the hobbits, and waits for Frodo, Sam, Merry, and Pippin to return.  They arrive and battle with Saruman, who is in the end betrayed by Wormtongue.  Wormtongue in turn is killed by the hobbit forces.
- 3021 - Frodo and Bilbo depart for the Grey Havens.  Gandalf and many elves go with them.  Sam, Merry, and Pippin see them off.

See also [The Lord of the Rings Wikia](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page) for more information on the names and places herein.

Answer (score 18):

The existing answers look good, but if you have a copy of the Lord of the Rings on you, just look in Appendix B, 'The Tale of Years'. There you will find a complete timeline of the second and third age, with the years 3018 and 3019 (where the story in LotR happened) in extra detail.

Comment: +1 for this; I would have thought it was the most obvious source and am surprised it took so long for someone to mention it.  Tolkien also made a "synoptic time scheme" which is as yet unpublished but referenced in Hammond & Scull; what's interesting is that it contains some additional and otherwise unknown info (such as that Sauron personally killed Shagrat after the latter brought the Mithril shirt/etc to Barad-dur).

Comment: @JimmyShelter Wow, what book is that exactly? Have you got any other cool facts like that?

Comment: This one: http://www.amazon.com/Lord-Rings-Readers-Companion/dp/0618642676/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1390143844&sr=1-1&keywords=lord+of+the+rings+readers+companion

Comment: @JimmyShelter Thanks! btw, new question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48460/what-did-ships-in-middle-earth-look-like :D

Comment: An excellent answer was recently added which has image captures of the [synoptic time scheme](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/254496/2868) referenced in Hammond & Scull.

Answer (score 15):

### Tolkien himself made a very detailed fourteen page Synoptic Time-Scheme

This is kept at Marquette University, at shelfmark [Mss-4/2/18/1a-8a](https://www.marquette.edu/library/archives/Mss/JRRT/JRRT-seriesa4.php). A complete transcript of the time scheme has been published in full in [Tolkien Studies 19, 2022 Supplement](https://muse.jhu.edu/issue/48264) as "*The Chronology of the Lord of the Rings*", and prior to that various transcribed excerpts have been included in *The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion*. Additionally manuscript scans of the full time scheme were reproduced in *JRR Tolkien The Art of the Manuscript* and prior to that a few pages were reproduced elsewhere.

William M. Fliss, archivist at Marquette university, describes the time-scheme as follows:

> As Tolkien wrote The Lord of the Rings he became preoccupied with time and distance, resulting in some archival gems. Among the manuscripts are synoptic time-schemes where Tolkien tracked the movements of different characters in the story. Resembling a spreadsheet in an age before Microsoft Excel, these schemes contain columns representing characters or groups of characters and rows representing days. Tolkien strove to synchronize the movements of characters on every day for much of the story. Tolkien seems to have created the final version of the time-scheme in the late 1940s as he completed the manuscript. This time-scheme is fifteen pages in length, but only nine of the pages have the spreadsheet format. The first two pages comprise a single listing of important dates, from the birthday party at Bag End on September 22nd until January 15th. Before I saw this time-scheme I never fully appreciated the importance of January 15th to the course of events. On that day Gandalf the Grey fought the Balrog on the Bridge of Khazad-dȗm and fell into the shadow of Moria. It was also the day when, to use an anachronism, the clock started ticking on the Fellowship. We learn from the time-scheme that when night fell on January 15th messages were sent forth from Moria to Isengard and to Mordor, setting evil forces in motion. Suddenly questions confronted Tolkien such as how long would it take for the message to reach Barad-dȗr? How exactly would it get there? When would Grishnákh and company be sent from Mordor? How quickly would they travel? The need for such a day-by-day reckoning intensified on February 26th with the Breaking of the Fellowship. Suddenly this tight group of characters that had moved together through Book II splinters in different directions, and Tolkien must track their every move.
> <sub>[Fliss, William M. (2017) "“Things That Were, and Things That Are, and Things That Yet May Be”: The J.R.R. Tolkien Manuscript Collection at Marquette University," *Mythlore: A Journal of J.R.R. Tolkien, C.S. Lewis, Charles Williams, and Mythopoeic Literature*: Vol. 36 : No. 1 , Article 3.](https://epublications.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1103&context=lib_fac)</sub>

What follows are images of the manuscript itself, from a variety of sources. For a full readable transcript please consult *The Chronology of the Lord of the Rings*, pages 34-86.

- Page 1 - Sept 22-Oct 15: (Can be seen in [this reddit picture from the NY Strong Museum of Play.](https://www.reddit.com/r/tolkienfans/comments/m981on/what_did_tolkien_write_withon/grlno6c/) Also published in *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 133):

[image: Page 1]

- Page 2 - Oct 16-Jan 15: Published in *Voyage en Terre du Milieu* pg 271 and *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 133.

[image: Page 2]

- Page 3 - Jan 15-Jan 22: Published in *Voyage en Terre du Milieu* pg 272 and *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 135.

[image: Page 3]

- Page 4:  Jan 23-Feb 16: Published in *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 135.

[image: Page 4]

- Page 5:  Feb 17-Feb 25: Published in *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 136

[image: Page 5]

- Page 6 - Feb 26-Feb 29: Published in *Maker of Middle-earth* pg 352-3, *Voyage en Terre du Milieu* pg 273, and *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 136

[image: Page 6]

- Page 7: Feb 30-Mar 3: Published in *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 137

[image: Page 7]

- Page 8 - Mar 4-Mar 7: Published in *Voyage en Terre du Milieu* pg 273 and *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 137

  [image: Page 8]
- Page 9 - Mar 8-Mar 12: Published in *The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion*, frontispiece, and *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 138

  [image: Page 9]
- Page 10 - Mar 13-17:  Published in *The Invented Worlds of J.R.R. Tolkien: Drawings and Original Manuscripts from the Marquette University Collection* pg 37, and *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 138

  [image: Page 10]
- Page 11:  Mar 18-25: Published in *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 139.

  [image: Page 11]
- Page 12:  Apr 8-Aug 10: Published in *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 140.

  [image: Page 12]
- Page 13:  Aug 14-Sep 22: Published in *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 140.

  [image: Page 13]
- Pages 14:  Oct 5-Oct 6: Published in *The Art of the Manuscript* pg 141.

  [image: Page 14]

Comment: Thank you for adding this outstanding and enlightening answer!

Comment: I was honestly looking for something a little more detailed. Oh well, I suppose this will have to do.

Comment: Thanks for including all the bits and pieces. Certainly looking forward to seeing what sort of stuff was happening 'off-page', if and when the edited version of all this gets published.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - Here's a ping to tell you that it's been published.

Comment: @ibid awesome, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 8):

Just for completeness' sake, I want to add to the already excellent answers with the LotRProject, a set of interactive charts and infographics based on *The Lord of the Rings* and other works in Tolkien's legendarium. They have a fantastic [interactive timeline](http://lotrproject.com/timeline/) of events synchronized with a map of Middle-earth that lets you track events by time, by protagonist or by location:

[image: LotRProject Timeline]

Answer (score 4):

I found [this nice and fairly thorough timeline](https://web.archive.org/web/20120103172323/http://tuckborough.net/chronology.html#Great-Years).  I can't vouch entirely for its accuracy, but it seems to tally with my recollection, so it's probably good enough.

Some important milestones:

September 22, 3001 - Bilbo leaves the Shire for Rivendell.
April 13, 3018 - Gandalf tells Frodo about the ring.
Sept 26, 3018 - The Hobbits leave the Shire.
October 20, 3018 - The Hobbits and Aragorn arrive at Rivendell.
December 25, 3018 - The Hobbits leave Rivendell.
March 25, 3019 - The ring is destroyed.

So, a bit under a year after they knew Frodo had to leave, six months from them actually leaving.  But nearly 18 years between Frodo inheriting the ring and its destruction.

Answer (score 4):

To supplement the existing answers, not supplant them, I offer [this link](http://lotrproject.com/timedistance/) to an interactive infographic of Time and Distance Traveled in *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings*.  I can't share an image of the graphic here, since it is interactive, but it is pretty interesting and allows you to zoom in on individual days.  The calendar used is apparently the Shire calendar, and each month has 30 days.  It is a bit odd to see "February 30".

Answer (score 2):

**20 years**. Bilbo was 131 at the end when he and Frodo left Middle-earth, it was his 111th birthday at the beginning of *The Fellowship of the Ring*.

Answer (score 0):

According to Barbara Strachey's *[Journeys of Frodo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journeys_of_Frodo)* the entire round trip started and ended almost a year and a month to the day from the 23rd Sept to 26th Oct the following year — though it would appear they had 2–3 months respite at Minas Tirith after the Mt Doom moment on 25th March. I presume a year later Frodo & Co depart for Grey Havens on 21st Sept, meet Gandalf the next day and arrive at the Gray Havens 7 days later, 29th Sept.

Comment: Do you have the relevant quote for this you can [edit] in?

Comment: The question asked how much time elapsed from the start of *The Fellowship of the Ring* to the end of *The Return of the King*. Instead, you have chosen say how long Frodo was away from The Shire, but you missed by a few days. According to Appendix B, the hobbits arrived at the bridge over the Brandywine on the evening of 30 October, not 26 October. As earlier answers have pointed out, *Fellowship* starts with Bilbo's 111th birthday, about 17 years before Frodo left The shire.

Answer (score -4):

At the end of the Return of the King film, when Frodo, Samwise, Meriadoc and Pippin return to the Shire, its said that "13 months to the day"

So... 13 months. In the film verse anyway