# What did Bilbo Baggins do while the Fellowship of the Ring went on their quest?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Bilbo is responsible for leaving the One Ring for Frodo, who subsequently became hunted by the Nazgûl, Saruman, Sauron, and even Boromir in a way. Yet in the Peter Jackson film *Fellowship of the Ring*, we come across Bilbo in Rivendell kind of just hanging out -- he gives Frodo all his weaponry and armour, tells Frodo he is sorry he brought Frodo into the whole One Ring mess, and then basically bids Frodo adieu and watches as Frodo sets off on the Fellowship of the Ring quest.

Almost all races are involved in the war to destroy the Ring. **But what does Bilbo do during the quest of the Fellowship?** Does he simply remain in Rivendell and work on his memoir? **Is there any information regarding Bilbo and what he did while the quest of the Fellowship of the Ring was ongoing? What did he do during the time the One Ring was being taken to Mt. Doom?**

<sub>**ETA:** The usual caveat. I've read *The Fellowship of the Ring* and *The Two Towers*, but have not read *The Silmarillion* or *The Return of the King*. I've seen Peter Jackson's *Lord of the Rings Trilogy* many times. I just got *The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey* on BD this past Tuesday, so I'm pretty unfamiliar with it still. I.e. I'm not a Tolkien scholar, so please pardon me if this is an obvious question to those in the know.</sub>

Comment: +1, I have no idea why this was downvoted.  I always thought it was an odd gap in the timeline as well...

Comment: You haven't read The Return of the King? Come on. There are some very excellent parts that aren't in the movie.

Comment: @Plutor - for better or worse, the community consensus was that [reading/watching the source material is NOT required before asking a question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2372/i-havent-read-the-book-watched-the-movie-may-i-ask-a-question-about-it/).

Comment: My comment wasn't meant as a criticism of the question. I thought it was a fine question. I was just making a (firm) suggestion.

Comment: This question seems trivial at best, and while @phantom42 mentions that it is not required to read the source material before asking a question, that does not make a question that is answered in the source material worthy for up vote, nor does it guarantee an absence of down votes. It is not *explicitly* mentioned that he did nothing during the events of LOTR, because *implicitly* that is exactly what he did, nothing.

Comment: Probably I am mistaken, but I remember that he went to the Lone Mountain during that period(?) I have this feeling but I don't know whether this is written in the appendices, or somewhere else or whether Bilbo simply mentioned this, as a possibility, *before* going to Rivendell.

Comment: @Plutor - Oh, believe me, *Return of the King* is on my to-read list for sure! I just haven't yet. I also need to re-read *The Hobbit*. While I know the movie isn't proper canon, watching *The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey* made me realize how much I've forgotten over the years. :)

Comment: @phantom42 consensus was that "not reading the source material" was not grounds for *closure*; it doesn't mean people won't consider it a bad question anyway.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, I know and I get that. But that's where things start getting fuzzy. According to the button, DVs are for unclear or poorly researched questions. How easy is it to find this info if you haven't read the book(s)?

Comment: Fuzzy for me, at least. I know we all have our different reasons and definitions for downvotes and all.

Comment: @phantom42 I would consider not reading the source material as the definition of poor research; if you want to ask a question without reading the source material first, we won't *close* it, but don't expect people to  be happy about it :) But at least it's likely to get answered anyway.

Comment: Always thought he spent the entire time smoking pipe 'weed'. It explains why he was all sleepy and tired all the time. Classic symptoms of old Toby.

Comment: @SumanRoy - I suspect I am not alone in thinking some Old Toby might have helped in getting through J.R.R. Tolkien's dry writing. Love the universe; not so keen on Tolkien's prose. YMMV, of course. :)

Comment: What was Bilbo up to? Elf-maidens and mai-tai's, my friend.

Comment: This is a good example of how LotR is _not_ a "trilogy"!  There are no pay-offs in the first two volumes (or the first four books, if you want), just cliffhangers.  All resolutions happen at the end of the story.  This separate volumes nonsense makes no sense now that the whole thing has been published for decades.  More money for the publishers, though.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Advance warning**: I'm going to assume that the fact that you've asked this question, despite having **not** read RotK, means that you **don't mind** being spoilered on anything in RotK.

If this assumption is false, then *stop reading this answer* and *start reading RotK*.  **Now**.

**End of advance warning**.

When the Hobbits get back to Rivendell, Bilbo has grown *old*.  He's sleepy, he doesn't get much done, he feels the end of his life coming on.

> They found him all alone in his little room. It was littered with papers and pens and pencils; but Bilbo was sitting in a chair before a small bright fire. He looked very old, but peaceful, and sleepy.

From Bilbo himself:

> "Do you know, I shall be one hundred and twenty-nine? And in one year more, if I am spared, I shall equal the Old Took. I should like to beat him; but we shall see."

Some general behaviour:

> ...they sat much with their old friend, who spent most of his time now in his room...At first he pretended to take some notes; but he often fell asleep; and when he woke he would say: 'How splendid! How wonderful! But where were we?' Then they went on with the story from the point where he had begun to nod.

He gets forgetful:

> Then he gave Frodo his mithril-coat and Sting, forgetting that he had already done so ... 'what's become of my ring, Frodo, that you took away?'

His poem:

> The Road goes ever on and on
>   Out from the door where it began.
>   Now far ahead the Road has gone,
>   Let others follow it who can!
>   Let them a journey new begin,
>   But I at last with weary feet
>   Will turn towards the lighted inn,
>   My evening-rest and sleep to meet.

Sam's observation:

> 'I don't think, Mr. Frodo, that he's done much writing while we've been away. He won't ever write our story now.'

Bilbo's reply:

> 'You see, I am getting so sleepy,' he said. 'And when I have time to write, I only really like writing poetry.'

And much much more.

This is not a Hobbit who is going to *do* anything while the Fellowship were away.  This is an old Hobbit at the end of his life.  If all that you have to go by is Jackson's movie, you're not going to get the full weight of this.  So I'll end as I started: *read RotK*.

Comment: No, no, the Jackson movies are a nice visual representation of Tolkien's world, but the books are really where it's at. I was merely sharing what experience(s) I have with the books versus the movies. In fact, part of what prompted me to ask this question was the possibility that Jackson had merely cut Bilbo's role out of the films and I wasn't sure. Thank you for a really nice answer and, no, I don't mind spoilers at all. In fact, I always read the last chapter of a book first -- I'm *that* bad when it comes to spoilers :) +1

Comment: I actually think this is a better answer than the most upvoted one.

Comment: You mean you'll end as you started, right? :P

Comment: I'll also point out that this isn't really spoiling anything for anyone who's seen the movies. You see this Bilbo-as-extremely-elderly while they head to the Grey Havens. The only real difference with (this part of) the book is that the hobbits stop in Rivendell on their way back to The Shire.

Comment: @Junuxx: "*You mean you'll end as you started, right? :P*" - yup; you win the prize for spotting the deliberate mistake!  Plutor - you're probably right, although the movie does underplay it a little, and I'm conscious that (and this *is* an individual preference) some may take exception to even this much of a reveal.

Comment: Yet we don't know if Bilbo decayed shortly after the ring was destroyed which leaves plenty of time for some action. When we first see him in Rivendell in fellowship, he remains in good shape.

Answer (score 38):

Bilbo had given the ring up almost two decades before and though he reacted strongly to it when it reappeared, he recovered his composure. The books are infused with the idea that Hobbits are for some reason less affected by the One Ring's miasma--not unaffected, but resistant.

Further he was an old, *old* Hobbit and was aware of the demands of questing and his own limitations.

Bilbo had for a long time been contented with his maps and his writing, he was presumably happy as a clam living in Rivendell, and I see no reason to suppose that he did anything more than bug Elrond for updates rather more often than they were available.

Comment: And eat copious amounts of Lembas bread.

Comment: I just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly. Bilbo gave Frodo the One Ring twenty years before the Fellowship of the Ring began its quest?

Comment: Well, I'm working from memory here but the big birthday party was for Bilbo's eleventy-first birthdays, and I seem to recall that he was 133 around the time of *The Lord of the Rings*. Someone with the source material in front of them may be able to give you more exact dates. Hmmm...I see below that I was recalling things a little later than they were. Will edit.

Comment: @aSlytherin [Yup](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7318/1027), roughly 20 years passed between Bilbo's party and the Ring's destruction.

Comment: Huh! I didn't know that. Thanks for clarifying that information because I'll admit I thought the time frame was around the same as it was in Peter Jackson's movies.

Comment: @aSlytherin The movies are pretty terrible when it comes to conveying the passage of time.  Every time you see a montage of the group walking somewhere, weeks/months are passing, but I never get that feeling from watching the films.

Comment: My memory is that Bilbo offers to take up the ring and go to destroy it at the Council of Elrond, but Gandalf essentially says no.

Comment: @Keen - that may be true, but most of that time passed between the party and Gandalfs return to Frodo.  Just a few months after that meeting passed before Frodo set out on the actual journey to Rivendell with the other Hobbits.

Comment: @Slytherincess Bilbo's 111th birthday party was on Sept 22nd in TA (Third Age) 3001 according to the books. The Fellowship set out from Rivendell on Dec 25 3018, and the Ring was destroyed on March 25th 3019.

Answer (score 11):

I can't improve on dmkee's answer, but I'll add this just for completeness' sake:
(By the way, this is from Chapter 1, right after the Party)

> [Bilbo:] "Well I've made up my mind, anyway. I want to see mountains again, Gandalf – *mountains*; and then find somewhere where I can *rest*. In peace and quiet, without a lot of relatives prying around, and string of confounded visitors hanging on the bell. I might find somewhere where I can finish my book. I have thought of a nice ending for it: *and he lived happily ever after to the end of his days*."

and this is one or two pages later:

> "I am being swept off my feet at last."

This seems to suggest that he wants to go out walking again, and *then* go to Rivendell, and consume copious amounts of *Lembas* (see dmkee's answer).

I also found this in the *Tale of Years* (Appendix B):

> 3001 Bilbo's farewell feast [september]. Gandalf . . . 
>   3002 Bilbo becomes a guest of Elrond, and settles in Rivendell.

That gives us a rough timeline.

Comment: While true, and an excellent point, it doesn't really answer the question of what he did *while the fellowship was on their quest* (e.g. 3019 TA)

Comment: @SSumner He writes his book and bugs Elrond, as in dmkee's answer. I just though I could add to that answer, giving some extra information.

Comment: No, I don't think that's necessary. Maybe just a short line at the beginning "In addition to dmckee's answer...". I don't think it was bad to post this, it's just supplementary information (I upvoted your answer, btw)

Comment: @SSumner Thanks for the hint and thanks for the upvote :-)

Comment: +1 for "*and he lived happily ever after to the end of his days*" - reading over the early LotR drafts in HoME, one can see how much of a bother this particular line was to Tolkien, and how much effort he put into avoiding any further adventures for Bilbo because of it.

Comment: Also +1 for Bilbo living happily ever after to the end of his days :)

Comment: Rivindell -> Rivendell

Comment: @FaheemMitha Oop, thanks!