# Does a transcription of Tolkien's handwriting in this image exist? (Part 2)

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, j-r-r-tolkien, the-two-towers, tolkiens-legendarium

Following on the success we had transcribing the text in the image on [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91085/does-a-transcription-of-tolkiens-handwriting-in-this-image-exist/) question, I am hoping that lightning will strike twice.  This image contains far more text, and is even less legible.  It comes from an early draft of the chapter "The Stairs of Cirith Ungol" in *The Two Towers*.  The sketch on the left is Tolkien's rendering of Shelob's Lair.

[image]

I was able to read a bit of the text, and it clearly isn't exactly the same as the text in the finished book.  The portion I could decipher says:

> "No, I don't think so,' said Frodo. 'He is up to no good, of course, but I don't think that he's gone to fetch orcs'"

The closest thing to this that appears in the book is:

> `No, I don't think so,' answered Frodo. 'Even if he's up to some wickedness, and I suppose that's not unlikely, I don't think it's that: not to fetch Orcs, or any servants of the Enemy."
>   -*The Lord of the Rings, The Two Towers, Book IV, Chapter 8: "The Stairs of Cirith Ungol"*

So the draft was obviously revised a bit before it was finally published, and I would like to know what the draft says, so I can compare it to the finished product, so to speak.

Slightly larger versions of the image are available [here](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8876/18349787635_6abf4d8ee0_o_d.jpg) and [here](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8882/17729354633_6842a0d573_o_d.jpg).  A much larger version of part of the page is available [here](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8841/18351493831_f66530068a_o_d.jpg).  It also appears as the frontispiece to the book *The War of the Ring*.

---

*Note 1:  Once again, I will offer a bounty of 500 rep points if you choose to transcribe it yourself, although I am not asking you to do so.*

*Note 2:  Having compared the transcripts here with the books, it appears that the contents of this manuscript page were later spread across parts of 3 separate chapters, and little, if any, of the original manuscript text made it into the books without revision.*

*Note 3:  Special thanks to Rand al'Thor for all his hard work.  He gets the bounty of 500 points.  Thanks also go to Jason Baker for copying the official transcript for his answer;  he will get a bounty of 100 points.*

Comment: "That's that," said Sam... and there I give up :P

Comment: Better quality image here: https://www.tolkienestate.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/677azz0064.jpg

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The page in question is from Tolkien's first draft of what would eventually become Book IV Chapter 8 of *The Two Towers*, which Christopher Tolkien dates to May-ish of 1944. The original page, according to *HoME*, is in Oxford's [Bodelian Library](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Bodleian_Library).

Christopher Tolkien transcribed this page in *History of Middle-earth* VIII:

> The [verso](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/verso#English) of the page, numbered '[7]', carrying the picture of the ascent to the pass, has the following text:
>
> > 'That's that' said Sam. 'What I expected. But I don't like it. I suppose now we are just exactly where he wanted to bring us. Well, let's get moving away as quick as we can. The treacherous worm! That last whistle of his wasn't pure joy at getting out of the tunnel, it was pure wickedness of some sort. And what sort we'll soon know.'
> >
> > 'Likely enough,' said Frodo. 'But we could not have got even so far without him. So if we ever manage out errand, then Gollum and all his wickedness will be part of the plan.'
> >
> > 'So far, you say,' said Sam. 'How far? Where are we now?'
> >
> > 'About at the crest of the main range of Ephel-duath, I guess,' said Frodo. 'Look!' The road opened out now: it still went on up, but no longer sheerly. Beyond and ahead there was an ominous glare in the sky, and like a great notch in the mount wall a cleft was outlined against it - so [here is a small sketch]. On their right the wall of rock fell away and the road widened till it had no brink. Looking down Frodo saw nothing but the vast darkness of the great ravine which was the head  of Morghul dale. Down in its depths was the faint glimmer of the wraith-road that led over the Morghul pass from the city. On their left sharp jagged pinnacles stood up like towers carved by the biting years, and between them were many dark crevices and clefts. But high up on the left side of the cleft to which their road led (Kirith Ungol) was a small black tower, and in it a window showed a red light.
> >
> > 'I don't like the look of that,' said Sam. 'This upper pass is guarded too. D'you remember he never would say if it was or no. D'you think he's gone to fetch them - orcs or something?'
> >
> > 'No, I don't think so,' said Frodo. 'He is up to no good, of course, but I don't think that he's gone to fetch orcs. Whatever it is, it is no slave of the Dark Lord's.' 'I suppose not,' said Sam. 'No, I suppose the whole time it has been the ring for poor Smeagol's own. That's been his scheme. But how coming up here will help him, I can't guess.' He was soon to learn.
> >
> > Frodo went forward now - the last lap - and he exerted all his strength. He felt that if once he could get to the saddle of the pass and look over into the Nameless Land he would have accomplished something. Sam followed. He sensed evil all round him. He knew that they had walked into some trap, but what? He had sheathed his sword, but now he drew it in readiness. He halted for a moment, and stooped to pick up his staff with his left hand.
>
> <sup><sub>*History of Middle-earth* VIII *The War of the Ring* Part 2: "The Ring Goes East" Chapter VIII: "Kirith Ungol"</sub></sup>

Comment: Argh! All that effort, and ninja'd by 48 seconds by a canon answer! :-( I may try and update/complete my answer anyway, without looking at yours...

Comment: @randal'thor - do not despair.  It appears that Christopher Tolkien made some mistakes.  I think the first line says "What we I expected".  :)

Comment: @WadCheber the we is crossed I think -- there's definatley a straight line there but its hard to tell xD not that I would have made that out that without knowing what the sentance says haha

Comment: Did you copy and paste this, @JasonBaker?  If so, Christopher Tolkien did indeed make at least one mistake - in the first paragraph, Sam says "...let's get moving away as quick as we can", not "...let's get moving away **just** as quick as we can"

Comment: @WadCheber No, I copied it out from the book. I'm not at home right now, but when I get back I'll check and see if it was his error or mine

Comment: @JasonBaker - I found a PDF of the transcript.  It appears that you inserted the "just".

Comment: @JasonBaker - If I can, I will give you a bounty of 100 points.  I'm not sure if I can do it, but I think I can.

Comment: @WadCheber You are indeed correct. Fixed now; thanks for the catch!

Comment: @WadCheber It's certainly possible to give more than one bounty, but you must give the smaller one first, and the second must be at least double the first. So you can for example give 100 and 500, but you must give the 100 first, then after it's awarded you can do 500.

Comment: Your answer gets accepted because it more directly answers the question, and you get 100 rep for copying it from the book, but rand gets the brass ring and 500 points for transcribing it by hand.

Answer (score 48):

### Transcribed by hand

> "That's that!" said Sam. What <del>we</del> I expected. And I don't like it. I suppose now we are just exactly where he wanted to bring us. Well, let's get moving away as quick as we can. The treacherous worm! That loud whistle of his wasn't pure joy at getting out of the tunnel, it was pure wickedness of some sort. And what sort we'll soon know.
>
> Likely enough, said Frodo. And we could not have got even so far without him. So if we ever manage our errand, then Gollum and all his wickedness will be part of the plan.
>
> So far you say, said Sam. How far? Where are we now?
>
> About at the crest of the mountain range Ephel Duath, I guess, said Frodo. Look!" The road opens out now: it still went on up, but no longer sheerly. Beyond and ahead there was an ominous glare in the sky, and like a great notch in the mountain wall or cleft was outlined against it - So *[picture]* On their right the wall of rock fell away and the road widened till it had no brink. Looking down Frodo saw only <del>but a</del> the vast darkness of the great ravine which was the head of Morghul Vale. Down in the depths was the faint glimmer of the wraith-road that led over the Morghul pass [**far west? from the city? from the west?**] On their left sharp jagged pinnacles, stood up like towers carved by the [**biting?**] years, and between them were many dark crevices and clefts. But high up on the left side of the cleft [**to? by?**] which their road led (K. Ungol [SIC]) was a small black tower, and in it a window [**shone? shined?**] a red light.
>
> "I don't like the look of that, said Sam. This upper pass is guarded too. D'you remember he never would say if it was or no. D'you think he's gone to fetch them - orcs or something?
>
> No, I don't think so, said Frodo. He is up to no good, of course, but I don't think that he's gone to fetch orcs. Whatever he is, he's no slave of the Dark Lord. I suppose not, said Sam. No, I suppose the whole time it's been the ring for poor Smeagol's own. That's been his scheme. But how coming up here will help him, I can't guess." He was soon to learn.
>
> Frodo went forward now - the last lap - and he exerted all his strength. He felt that if once he could get to the saddle of the pass and look over into the Nameless Land he would have accomplished something. Sam followed. He sensed evil all around him. He knew that they had walked into some trap, but what? He had sheathed his sword, but now he drew it in readiness. He halted for a moment, and stooped to pick up his staff with his left hand.

(Tolkien hasn't been too consistent with inverted commas, I notice!)

Transcribing this has reminded me how great Tolkien's writing is. I need to reread LotR some time...

Thanks to **Wad Cheber** (the OP) for help with deciphering parts of the writing.

Comment: I'm very impressed with how close you were to the "correct" version; +1 from me, for the effort alone

Comment: +1 for sure.  End of second to last paragraph- "He was soon to learn".  I suggest that you let others help with the transcription, without reference to Jason's answer.  I will probably accept his answer, but give you the bounty, since you worked harder.

Comment: @WadCheber Thanks, but I'd already worked out "He was soon to learn" by the time I saw your comment :-) This job gets easier as time goes on, because I'm getting more used to the handwriting. And of course contributions from all and sundry will be appreciated!

Comment: @randal'thor - Be glad you're not Christopher Tolkien.  He had to transcribe [this](http://i.imgur.com/xmFmXwf.jpg?1)!

Comment: @WadCheber Doesn't look _toooo_ bad. Want to post that as a question here too? ;-)

Comment: @WadCheber Again, last sentence already done by the time your comment came up! I'm editing all the time, but I think I'm nearing the limit of what I can do alone.

Comment: @WadCheber Couldn't it be "What we'd expected"? PS. Just that big paragraph left now!

Comment: "shored up like houses"? "stormed up like trees"? "carved by the" _what_???

Comment: OK @WadCheber, it's all yours to edit now. I'll come back later when I have the book to hand - maybe some of this text was actually used, which would make it easier!

Comment: @randal'thor - That's as much as I can do.  See if you can fill in the blanks.

Comment: @randal'thor - You get the 500 point bounty.  Many thanks.

Comment: "I'm not asking you to, but this is the internet, so I know someone will" ≈)

Comment: @WadCheber I just realised that a transfer of 500 points from you to me will put me above you in rep! I feel bad now - I don't think I deserve to have more points than you. You've contributed so much to the LotR stuff on this site...

Comment: @corsiKa - Richard told me that *asking* people to translate it would be off topic, but *allowing* people to translate it would not.  :)

Comment: @randal'thor - so have you.  No biggie.  Besides, I earned all this rep in about a month.  I'll be back where I am now within a week or so.  Maybe I should split the 500 - 400 to you, 100 to Jason.  We'll see.

Comment: @randal'thor - 23 hours until I can award the bounty.  You deserve it.  I've contributed more questions than answers.  You actually answer stuff.

Comment: @randal'thor - You're a whopping 272 points ahead of me now.  No big deal.

Comment: @WadCheber Thanks for the bounty! :-D I only reached 3k recently and now I'm coming up to 5k. Looking forward to more of your questions :-)

Comment: @randal'thor I just got The Lord of the Rings:  A Reader's Companion, and the Frontispiece is a great picture of another page from the Synoptic Time Scheme, from my first transcription question.  If I can get a clear photo of it I might ask another question along these lines.  The handwriting is actually very legible (in fact, it is quite beautiful).

Comment: @randal'thor - It is so easy to read that it doesn't make sense to start a new question about it.  Here is a crappy photo of it.  https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8887/18616597681_c9d9c227e8_o_d.jpg